# How to get Jetty load resources from a JAR file?

Tags: jsf, jar, jetty, web-content

I'm running JSF application on Jetty 8. I have one jar file with web resources (/META-INF/resources/test.xhtml) for some reason context from that resource is not added to WebAppContext. When I'm using maven jetty plugin then server adds web context and file 'test.xhtml' can be accessed.

How to get Jetty load resources from a JAR file?

Comment: I know this isn't explicitly an answer - I'm struggling with the same. So war, using jetty-runner is a workaround which works for me, but I don't feel it's the resolution